# Set text on a textview instantiated in main activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a main activity class which instantiates the variables for my widgets and makes references to them with findViewById. I would like to be able to set the text on a textview from a separate class, however eclipse complains that the variables cannot be resolved. I have set the main activity widget variables to public. Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm new to android.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public TextView player1ScoreView;
    public TextView player2ScoreView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        player1ScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1ScoreTextView);
        player2ScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player2ScoreTextView);

    }
}

public class GamePlay {
    ...
    player1ScoreView.setText(num.format(player1score));
}
```

player1ScoreView isn't recognized in the separate class. Does GamePlay have to be an activity to be able to set the text on a widget? Please explain. Thanks in advance

Comment: GamePlay has no idea where player1ScoreView comes from because the 2 classes are separate. You could make a constructor for Gameplay take a parameter of type TextView and then pass it your player1ScoreView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple option is to pass TextView object(player1ScoreView) as a parameter in GamePlay class method. By passing this object you can set value for this object through this method of GamePlay class.

Refer code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public TextView player1ScoreView;
public TextView player2ScoreView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    player1ScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1ScoreTextView);
    player2ScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player2ScoreTextView);

    GamePlay gamePlay=new GamePlay();
    gamePlay.setViewValue(player2ScoreView);

 }
}

public class GamePlay {
...

public void setViewValue(TextView player2ScoreView)
  {
    player2ScoreView.setText(num.format(player1score));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instance of the GamePlay class must have a reference to your MainActivity object in oder to access its members.

```
public class GamePlay {
    ...
    MainActivity main = ...
    ....
    main.player1ScoreView.setText(num.format(player1score));
}
```

Of course it would be better to access is via a getter method.

I'm not sure how you'll pass the reference of the MainActivity to your GamePlay  object. It depends on how you create that object.

Comment: Thank you, totally blanked on that.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to send an instance of the `TextView` to the other class or return the value to set and set it in the `Activity`.

So, you could get an instance of that class then send the `TextView` to a method of that class and set it there.

```
gamePlay.setScore(player1ScoreView);
```

and in the class

```
public void setScore(TextView tv)
{
    tv.setText(num.formatplayer1score);
}
```

Or get the text to set from the gameplay class with something like

```
player1scoreview.setText(gameplay.getScore());
```

then have a method `getScore()` in your `GamePlay` class which would return a `String` to set the text as.